# QWebPage triggers loadFinished() several times

Tags: qt, qwebpage

I'm loading content into QWebPage, using load() method.
But my loadStarted(), loadFinished() and loadProgress() handlers are calling several times.
How can I detect that page is loaded completely with all it's content?

Comment: What page are you loading? Could it be that the page re-directs?

Comment: It's happening on almost any page. E.g. on google.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is QWebView.loadFinished called several times on some sites e.g. youtube?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775152/why-is-qwebview-loadfinished-called-several-times-on-some-sites-e-g-youtube)

Answer (score 1):

Posted a related solution proposal at:

[Receiving multiple loadFinished signals for a requested web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780261/receiving-multiple-loadfinished-signals-for-a-requested-web-page/28659995#28659995)

Basicly look for repaintRequested(QRect) signal of QWebPage.